# When to use Stored Procedures instead of using any ORM with programming logic?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, orm, preferences

Hi all I wanted to know when I should prefer writing stored procedures over writing programming logic and pulling data using a ORM or something else.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Stored procedures are executed on server side.

This means that processing large amounts of data does not require passing these data over the network connection.

Also, with stored procedures, you can build consistent complicated business logic.

Say, you need to update the account balance each time you insert a transaction, and you need to insert many transactions at once.

Instead of doing this with triggers (which are implemented using inefficient record-by-record approach in many systems), you can pass a table variable or temporary table with the inputs and issue a set-based `SQL` statement inside the procedure. This will be much more efficient.

Comment: +1 for a great insight that is often overlooked (or not mentioned).

Comment: @Joel: not all engines support table variables.

Comment: Ya never thought of using it over triggers...also i guess one of the things...is having logic on database side means you can reuse with any other platform or language...but ya your answer sums it up well..

Answer (score 3):

I prefer SPs over programming logic mainly for two reasons

- Performance, anything what will reduce result set or can be more effectively done on the server, e.g.:

  - paging
  - filtering
  - ordering (on indexed columns)
- Security -- if someone have got application's access to the database and wants to wipe out your all your records, having to execute `Row_Delete` for single each of them instead of `DELETE FROM Rows` already sounds good.

Comment: The paging/filtering/ordering would still be done server-side in any OR/M worth its salt.

Answer (score 2):

Never unless you identify a performance issue. (largely opinion)

(a Jeff blog post!)
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/10/who-needs-stored-procedures-anyways.html

If you see stored procs as optimizations:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize

Comment: In the old days, performance was an issue which is why that argument used to come up.  Today, most embedded sql can run as fast as stored procs.  Regardless, there are many additional reasons to use procs.

Comment: This topic is like abortion or gay marriage, you can't win when you argue it. Still, I will say that the only time I personally use stored procs is when my boss forces me to against my better judgement or when there is a production performance concern.

Comment: I like this quote: "Stored Procedures should be considered database assembly language: for use in only the most performance critical situations"

Comment: I actually pasted that quote into a comment before deciding not to use it. Definately an excellent analogy.

Comment: I should also add that ORM handling mass updates can be cumbersome - this may not be a problem for long but it is a compelling reason to use stored procs (a batch of update statements is less desirable than an update/where statement). Still, most of these situations can probably be handled as a one-off by a DBA as opposed to in code.

Answer (score 2):

When appropriate.

- complex data validation/checking logic
- avoid several round trips to do one action in the DB
- several clients
- anything that should be set based

You can't say "never" or "always".

There is also the case where the database engine will outlive your client code. I bet there's more DAL or ORM upgrades/refactoring that DB engine upgrades/refactoring going on.

Finally, why can't I encapsulate code in a stored proc? Isn't that a good thing?

Answer (score 1):

As ever, much of your decision as to which to use will depend on your application and its environment.

There are a couple of schools of thought here, and this debate always arouses strong sentiments on both sides.

The advantanges of Stored Procedures (as well as the large data moving that Quassnoi has mentioned) are that the logic is tied down in the database, and therefore potentially more secure.  It is also only ever in one place.

However, there will be others who believe that the place for application logic should be in the application, especially if you are planning to access other types of datebases (for which you will have to write often different SPs).

Another consideration may be the skills of the resources you have to implement your application.

Answer (score 1):

The point at which stored procedures become preferable to an ORM is that point at which you have multiple applications talking to the same database.  At this point, you want your query logic embedded in one place, rather than once per application.  And even here, you might want to prefer a service layer (which can scale horizontally) instead of the database (which only scales vertically).

Comment: Properly done, databases can scale out (vertically) just fine.

Comment: @Chris - you can add additional app servers much more easily than you can add additional db servers hosting the _same_ db.  Granted, being that big is one of those "good" problems to have.